# SQL count distinct values of another value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

say i have a table that looks like this column names (cusip_nbr, partc_nbr) lets called the table title table_cusip (sorry don't know how to format btw)

## cusip_nbr ----- partc_nbr

00162Q106 ------------ 0756 
00162Q106 ------------ 0231 
00162Q106 ------------ 0756
00162Q106 ------------ 0231 
231292106 ------------ 0412
231292106 ------------ 0395 
231292106 ------------ 0101 
231292106 ------------ 0291 
43129U101 ------------ 0756 
43129U101 ------------ 0395 
43129U101 ------------ 0921
43129U101 ------------ 0756

What SQL code can i write to return a table like (basically to look at the cusip_nbr and see how many distinct participant numbers there are per cusip_nbr)? -> 00162Q106 has 2 distinct members, 231292106 has 4, and 43129U101 has 3. (This is just a snip of my table i have probably 1,300 cusip_nbrs that i need to count members for)

## cusip_nbr ---- nbr_of_members

00162Q106 ----------------- 2 
23129106 --------------------4  
43129U101------------------ 3

Answer (score 6):

```
select cusip_nbr, count(distinct partc_nbr) as nbr_of_members
from table_cusip 
group by cusip_nbr
```

Comment: sorry but how would I take that result and insert the column nbr_of_members into another table column say called other_table column members

Comment: `insert into other_table (other_table_column) select count(distinct partc_nbr) as nbr_of_members
from table_cusip 
group by cusip_nbr`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do select with group-by

```
Select cusip_nbr, count(distinct partc_nbr)
from table_cusip 
group by cusip_nbr
```

Comment: This won't give the distinct count.